# How do you dynamically update the filename in a saved export in Access based on some other Access object?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating an Access macro to sequentially run the "RunSavedImportExport" action over several saved exports.

As far as I've been able to find, you can only hard-code the filename for the file your saved export will create - I'd like to somehow set up these saved exports to change the file's name based on a name in another object in Access.

For example, I have 3 tables in my Access database:

- *groceryList* is a basic table with data
- *errandsList* is a basic table with data
- *currentPerson* is a single row, single column table with that person's name in the single cell

People can save copies of this database for their own use and update *groceryList* and *errandsList* as they please, and populate *currentPerson* with their own name.

I would like these people to be able to run this macro I'm creating (*exportLists*) to run 2 saved exports:

- *exportGroceries* will create a file with the contents of *groceryList* in this location "F:\Users\MasterUser\Groceries\person name.txt"
- *exportErrands* will create a file with the contents of *errandList* in this location "F:\Users\MasterUser\Errands\person name.txt"

My problem: I'd like "person name" in both exports to use the single cell value from *currentPerson* rather than "person name". I'd be okay storing off this "person name" somewhere other than this *currentPerson* table - whatever would allow me to dynamically pull it into my saved export's filename.

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the export file name by changing the "Path" attribute of the Import/Export specification.

Each Import/Export Specification has:  Name, Description, and XML properties.

Below is some demonstrative VBA:

```
Sub ModifyImportExport()
    Dim IE As ImportExportSpecification

    For Each IE In CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
        'Debug.Print IE.Name
        'Debug.Print IE.XML
        If InStr(IE.XML, "Groceries") Then
            IE.XML = Replace(IE.XML, "Groceries", "Errands")
            Debug.Print IE.XML
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The XML of an Excel specification looks something like below (yours will undoubted be different, as you are exporting to txt):

```
<ImportExportSpecification Path = "F:\Users\MasterUser\Groceries\person name.xlsx" xmlns="urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec">
    <ExportExcel  AccessObject="groceryList" ObjectType="Table" ExcelFormat="Excel12Xml" Range="RangeName" />
</ImportExportSpecification>
```

You can inspect your existing specifications by printing all their values.  That will give you an idea of how to modify the specification for each condition:

```
Sub PrintImportExport()
    Dim IE As ImportExportSpecification

    For Each IE In CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
        Debug.Print IE.Name
        Debug.Print IE.XML
    Next
End Sub
```